# A question on Mean Value theorem on Separable Hilbert space

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory

Suppose $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is a mapping given to be twice frechet differentiable on $U$, where $U$ is a separable hilbert space.
$g:[0,T]\to U$ a continuous map.

Here, for $u\in U$, $f'(u)\in L(U,\mathbb{R})$ and $f''(u)\in L(U\times U, R)$.

Can we say that the following mean value theorem of this form holds?

for $a,b\in [0,T]$
$$f'(g(b))-f'(g(a))=f''(c)(g(b)-g(a))$$
for some $c\in g[a,b]$?

I only manage to find reference (attached) closest on this for a finite dimensional
$V$ and $f:V\to R$.

reference:
https://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/pschrimpf/526/calculus-526.pdf

I'm new in this stuffs any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is no; if I'm understanding correctly, you want a mean value theorem when the target space is $L(U,\mathbb{R})$, and the mean value theorem (as you stated it) is not true in that case: Think of the function $h(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$, then $0=h(2\pi)-h(0)$, but $h'(t)\neq 0$ for any $t$. (Also notice that $f'$ is not an element of $L(U\mathbb{R}$, but rather $f'\in C^0(U, L(U,\mathbb{R}))$ given your assumptions)

Comment: @Jose27 would it change a thing if $f'(u)\in L(U\mathbb{R})$ I made a type on f'

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The issue is that for vector valued functions you don't expect a mean value theorem like the one you stated.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you..  Yeah i encounter few MVT in terms inequalities far from this form..
 I guess i need to find alternatives for this..